# Javascript object/array looping and creating table problem

Tags: javascript, api, loops

This is my html code:

```js
function p1_podaci() {
  var p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
  zahtev = new XMLHttpRequest();
  zahtev.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (zahtev.readyState == 4 && zahtev.status == 200) {
      var podaci = JSON.parse(zahtev.responseText);

      var text = "<table border=1>";
      for (var pod of podaci) {
        text += "<tr>";

        for (pera in pod) {
          text += "<th>" + pera + "</th>";
        }
        text += "</tr>";


        text += "<tr>";
        for (var kljuc in pod) {
          text += "<td>" + pod[kljuc] + "</td>";
        }
        text += "</tr>";
      }
      text += "</table>";
      p1.innerHTML = text;
    }
  }


  zahtev.open("get", "https://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=fueloilexportsbycountryrecent&format=json&select=ID,Year,Country,Code,QuantityMetricTonsThousand&case=default&token=jU6ewy7mx8ClH7FcLTjDRCWnaITHMqgw", true);
  zahtev.send();
}
```

```html
<p>- Exports By Country [Fuel Oil] (recent):</p>
<button onclick="p1_podaci()">Click for more info...</button>
<p id="p1" class="yellow"></p><br><br>
```

As a result I get this table:
[image]

I don't want the table header repeats after every row, but to be only at the very top of the table (Only once like in every normal table). Does anyone have idea how to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: just get the headers from first record and take out `tr` element from loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the header from the 1st item if the array is not empty:

```js
function p1_podaci() {
  var p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
  var zahtev = new XMLHttpRequest();
  zahtev.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (zahtev.readyState == 4 && zahtev.status == 200) {
      var podaci = JSON.parse(zahtev.responseText);

      if (!podaci.length) return; // exist array is empty

      var text = "<table border=1>";

      text += "<tr>";

      for (pera in podaci[0]) { // iterate the 1st item and get the header
        text += "<th>" + pera + "</th>";
      }
      
      text += "</tr>";

      for (var pod of podaci) {
        text += "<tr>";
        for (var kljuc in pod) {
          text += "<td>" + pod[kljuc] + "</td>";
        }
        text += "</tr>";
      }
      text += "</table>";
      p1.innerHTML = text;
    }
  }


  zahtev.open("get", "https://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=fueloilexportsbycountryrecent&format=json&select=ID,Year,Country,Code,QuantityMetricTonsThousand&case=default&token=jU6ewy7mx8ClH7FcLTjDRCWnaITHMqgw", true);
  zahtev.send();
}
```

```html
<p>- Exports By Country [Fuel Oil] (recent):</p>
<button onclick="p1_podaci()">Click for more info...</button>
<p id="p1" class="yellow"></p><br><br>
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you Ori. This is a great explanation.